# Python wrap with class at specific index in list of lists and return whole list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples. I'd like to wrap each tuple's value at `index=1` with a class called `Paragraph()` then return the whole list.

```
description_index = 1
line_data = [
    ('1', 'PRODUCT 1<br/>new line', '1.00 pc', '1.00', '2,000.00', '2,000.00'), 
    ('100000', 'PRODUCT 2', '1.00 pc', '20.00', '5.00', '100.00')
]
```

Is there a faster / more efficient way to achieve this? In this example it doesn't take too long but what if the length increased to 1000 and `description_index=100`.

```
def wrap_with_paragraph(line_data):
    new_line_data = []
    for line in line_data:
        new_line_data.append([
            line[0],
            Paragraph(line[1]),
            line[2],
            line[3],
            line[5],
        ])
    return new_line_data
```

I've also tried using list comprehension but I'm not sure that it's going to be any faster.

```
def wrap_with_paragraph(line_data):
    return [
        [Paragraph(x) if i == 1 else x for i, x in enumerate(l)]
        for l in line_data
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since tuples are immutable (you can't `l[i] = P(l[i])`), you can use tuple slicing:

```
def wrap_with_paragraph(line_data, i):
    return line_data[:i] + (Paragraph(line_data[i]),) + line_data[i + 1:]a[i])
```

Comment: Awesome, that works. `[wrap_with_paragraph(line, 1) for line in line_data]`

Comment: I doubt it would be faster than using a list comprehension

Comment: How is this more efficient? It is at the very least, a tad bit less space efficient, although in the with the same asymptotic complexity...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't know a more efficient solution so if you know a better one I'd love to see it.

Comment: @bdoubleu there isn't any more algorithmically efficient solution, you are going to have to touch each element, so the best you can do is linear time. I don't think the above will be as performant for large `i`, though, simply because it makes several passes over the data, since you are using `list` slicing and concatenation, although for small lists, this is often faster because Python `list` objects implement these things in highly efficient code